# How to cache remote URL available offline?

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview, offline-caching

I am loading a uiwebview with the following code:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.example.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Is there any means to cache the website so its available offline if there is no connection?

Comment: u want to cache whole website

Comment: Depends .. if i load a url it should be able to cache it..

Answer (score 0):

The key is: `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`

```
  NSData *urlData;
  NSString *baseURLString =  @"mysite.com";
  NSString *urlString = [baseURLString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile"];

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 10.0]; 
  NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil]; 

  if (connection)
  { 
      urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request];

      NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURLString];
      [htmlString release];
  }

  [connection release];
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: its loading only the html i cannot see any css